# Problems migrate project from JDK 1.5 to JDK 1.7 & JBOSS 7.1

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to migrate a project (which contains web services) from JDK 1.5 to JDK 1.7 & trying to deploy it in JBOSS 7 but getting below errors as mentioned below:

```
10:12:26,930 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:12:27,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
10:12:29,869 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:12:29,870 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
10:12:29,936 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
10:12:29,951 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.network.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.management: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface management
    at org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:97) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]

10:12:30,120 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:37600
10:12:30,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
10:12:30,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
10:12:29,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
10:12:29,987 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
10:12:29,987 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
10:12:29,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:12:29,976 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
10:12:29,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:12:29,966 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
10:12:29,962 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
10:12:30,497 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:12:30,491 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:12:30,442 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
10:12:30,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-26) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:12:30,308 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:37600
10:12:30,982 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-18) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
10:12:31,295 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-31) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:37606
10:12:31,317 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-29) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments
10:12:31,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment apm_ws_jboss7.war
10:12:32,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.network.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.management: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface management

10:12:32,592 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
10:12:32,643 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 6952ms - Started 129 of 179 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 45 services are passive or on-demand)
10:12:33,730 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found apm_ws_jboss7.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called apm_ws_jboss7.war.dodeploy
10:12:33,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-26) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "apm_ws_jboss7.war"
10:12:43,495 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:43,618 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry batik-all-1.6.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:43,728 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry commons-io-1.3.1.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:43,874 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry fop-hyph.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:44,001 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry jai_codec.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:44,127 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry jai_core.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:44,259 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry jimi.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:44,397 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry serializer-2.7.0.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:44,541 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry servlet-2.2.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:44,670 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry xalan-2.7.0.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:44,789 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:44,934 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry xml-apis-1.3.02.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:45,089 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) Class Path entry xmlunit1.0.jar in "/usrdata/ksharma/jboss711/standalone/deployments/apm_ws_jboss7.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.94.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:12:47,782 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-20) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.josql.contrib.JoSQLJSPQueryTag due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.josql.contrib.JoSQLJSPQueryTag from [Module "deployment.apm_ws_jboss7.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]

10:12:48,599 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-20) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet from [Module "deployment.apm_ws_jboss7.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]

10:12:51,165 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-20) Add Service
 id=st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.EventServiceEndPoint
 address=http://eux.sg.com:37600/apm_ws/EventServiceEndPoint
 implementor=st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.EventServiceEndPoint
 invoker=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker
 serviceName={http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}EventServiceEndPointService
 portName={http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}EventServiceEndPointPort
 wsdlLocation=null
 mtomEnabled=false
10:12:51,385 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-20) Add Service
 id=st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.EightDServiceEndPoint
 address=http://eux.sg.com:37600/apm_ws/EightDServiceEndPoint
 implementor=st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.EightDServiceEndPoint
 invoker=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker
 serviceName={http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}EightDServiceEndPointService
 portName={http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}EightDServiceEndPointPort
 wsdlLocation=null
 mtomEnabled=false
10:12:51,596 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-20) Add Service
 id=st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.ActionServiceEndPoint
 address=http://eux.sg.com:37600/apm_ws/ActionServiceEndPoint
 implementor=st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.ActionServiceEndPoint
 invoker=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker
 serviceName={http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}ActionServiceEndPointService
 portName={http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}ActionServiceEndPointPort
 wsdlLocation=null
 mtomEnabled=false
10:12:51,821 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-20) Add Service
 id=st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.ActionPlanServiceEndPoint
 address=http://eux.sg.com:37600/apm_ws/ActionPlanServiceEndPoint
 implementor=st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.ActionPlanServiceEndPoint
 invoker=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker
 serviceName={http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}ActionPlanServiceEndPointService
 portName={http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}ActionPlanServiceEndPointPort
 wsdlLocation=null
 mtomEnabled=false
10:12:52,655 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-20) log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.DB1.layout
10:12:52,764 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-20) Creating Service {http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}EventServiceEndPointService from class st.qs.eventmgt.ws.endpoint.EventServiceEndPoint
10:12:52,944 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-20) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."apm_ws_jboss7.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."apm_ws_jboss7.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "apm_ws_jboss7.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An operation with name [{http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}loadUsers] already exists in this service
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:350)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:509)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:117)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:113)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:66)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An operation with name [{http://endpoint.ws.eventmgt.qs.st/}loadUsers] already exists in this service
    at org.apache.cxf.service.model.InterfaceInfo.addOperation(InterfaceInfo.java:71)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.createOperation(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:917)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.createOperation(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:621)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.createInterface(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:909)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:435)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:685)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:507)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:241)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:433)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:322)
    ... 13 more

10:12:54,467 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "apm_ws_jboss7.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"apm_ws_jboss7.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"apm_ws_jboss7.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"apm_ws_jboss7.war\""}}
10:12:56,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment apm_ws_jboss7.war in 1794ms
10:12:56,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."apm_ws_jboss7.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."apm_ws_jboss7.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "apm_ws_jboss7.war"

10:12:56,541 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"apm_ws_jboss7.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"apm_ws_jboss7.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"apm_ws_jboss7.war\""}}}}
```

Please help & thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using domain or standalone? also, did you change any configuration?

Comment: I am using standalone & I have not yet changed any configuration of this project (just compiled with jdk1.7).

Comment: Looks like you are using linux. Check the ip configuration of the machine using ifconfig. Check if this is related to this [Jboss thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/803800)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while migrating from *`jboss-as-7.1.3.Final`* to *`jboss-as-7.2.0.Final`*.
I was switching between two networks and hence had modified the interfaces tags in standalone *`xml`*.
The problem at my end was, `/etc/hosts` file had an entry for one `IP` of mine and not the other one. Once I removed that entry, both management and public interfaces were started.
I don't know if the issue is same, but thought I would share.